# Buttons always on the top - Android XML Layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm doing a layout for my app and in the green border is what I have. It is ScrollView and on the bottom are buttons. My question is, how can I block those buttons (red border) to be always on the top? I mean, they will show above buttons on the black background (I don't know how it calls). The blue border is showing size of the new ScrollView. I can add my code if you need.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl7Jj.jpg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="7dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tytul"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tytuł:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wyniktytul"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wynik tytul" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rezyser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reżyser:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wynikrezyser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wynik rezyser" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gatunek"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gatunek" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wynikgatunek"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wynik gatunek" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rokprodukcji"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rok produkcji:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wynikrokprodukcji"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wynik produkcja" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ocenauzytkownikow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ocena użytkowników:" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/gwiazdki"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
        android:text="Opis:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wynikopis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/opis"
        android:text="long text here" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@id/wynikopis"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Obejrzyj potem" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/wynikopis"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:text="Obejrzałem" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your xml code. Because it depends of the Layout you are using. If I understood your question, you want the red part to appear above everything else?

Comment: Red part should appear above those 4 buttons (back, home etc.) and over  the red part should starting ScrollView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give button outside ScrollView and put all to a **linearlayout**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight = "1"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="7dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tytul"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tytuł:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wyniktytul"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Wynik tytul" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rezyser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Reżyser:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wynikrezyser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Wynik rezyser" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gatunek"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Gatunek" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wynikgatunek"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Wynik gatunek" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rokprodukcji"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rok produkcji:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wynikrokprodukcji"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Wynik produkcja" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ocenauzytkownikow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ocena użytkowników:" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/gwiazdki"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/opis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
            android:text="Opis:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wynikopis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/opis"
            android:text="long text here" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Obejrzyj potem" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:text="Obejrzałem" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for help. This is what I wanted to get :)

Comment: I have just updated. We will close scrollview abover button parrent layout

Comment: One more thing. 
android:layout_below="@id/wynikopis" 
android:layout_below="@+id/wynikopis"
those lines are incorrected. They are underlined but everything is compling and it works.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand corectly, you want only the text to be scrollable, but the thing is .. you put the ScrollView as the parent of the whole layout. It should only child the View you want to make scrollable (in this case, the textView).

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="7dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tytul"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tytuł:"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wyniktytul"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wynik tytul"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rezyser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reżyser:"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wynikrezyser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wynik rezyser"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gatunek"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gatunek"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wynikgatunek"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wynik gatunek"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rokprodukcji"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rok produkcji:"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wynikrokprodukcji"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wynik produkcja"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ocenauzytkownikow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ocena użytkowników:"/>

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/gwiazdki"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
        android:text="Opis:"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/btBotLeft"
        android:layout_below="@id/opis">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wynikopis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="long text here"/>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btBotLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Obejrzyj potem"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:text="Obejrzałem"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I can't compile this. Everything look good. Error:(94, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/btBotLeft').

Comment: Hmm... it compiled fine for me